# Pre-process MVC Razor File For Multi-Lingual Language Strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my application we have multi-lingual language strings which are stored in custom tables, as the user can edit, delete, import new languages etc... via a UI

Currently, what I'm doing is at the beginning of each request is. I'm going off and getting all the language strings (From our database) for the currently selected language and sticking them in a dictionary.

I then have a Html Helper extension method which I use in the razor views (See below), which fishes in the dictionary I got at the beginning of the request to pull out the correct language based on the key supplied in the helper.

```
Html.LanguageString("MyLanguage.KeyHere")
```

Now this works fine. However, as the application is getting bigger. We are getting more and more language strings. It's not an issue right now, as its still very fast as there are only around 200 strings to get.

But this also means I'm getting all of them, even if a page has say one on it. I'd ideally like a way of processing the LanguageString("")'s before hand and doing a query to just get those that are needed at the beginning of the request? Or maybe my own linq based language that can be processed and product a more efficient call.

I'm looking for some advice on how to do this. As I'd like the application to be as efficient as possible. Any advice, help, tips are greatly received. Thanks.

Comment: I'm lost what that link has to do with my question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest caching language strings on the application basis rather than fetching them for every request. For example, this can be done by maintaining a static dictionary and invalidating the cache only when the user makes changes to these strings. This will make your application more responsive as well as save you from implementing (imho) rather more complex and not necessarily efficient technique of loading this data on-demand.

As a side note I'd add the following: it's usually a good practice to address these kinds of problems when they arise (rather than fixing something that is not broken) and focus on more important things. I totally agree that performance implications of a given solution must always be taken into consideration, I'm just saying that premature optimizations are not always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was debating on loading on app startup and updating on demand if a user changes them. I might look at that as an option.